# Checking the value of two checkboxes and entering a corresponding value into a database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

So what I am trying to achieve is I have two checkboxes.  One is for employee completion and the other for manager. The action I want when BOTH are checked (have a value of 2) is to check the the third checkbox named full complete and to enter a value of 2 into the database.

So far I have the following, however, the synax must be wrong because it will not allow me to have this && because it is boolean.

```
if($row['employee_complete'] == 2) && ($row['manager_complete'] == 2) { 
echo "<td>"."<input type = 'checkbox' checked='checked' name ='fullcomplete' value=      
'fullcomplete'/>"."</td>";
}
else
{
echo "<td>"."<input type = 'checkbox' name ='fullcomplete' value= 'full complete'/>"."  
</td>";
}
```

This also does not enter any value into the database, do I need to perform a full insert SQL query?

Things to perhaps consider:
-The checkboxes are echoed in a table inside an associative array.

Thank you.

Comment: Your syntax error is that you're missing a pair of brackets, while the comparison grouping is valid you need to encapsulate those within the if statement e.g. if(($row['employee_complete'] == 2) && ($row['manager_complete'] == 2))

Comment: more precisely, you're missing the if parentheses (not brackets)...

Comment: @Nathan yes, thank you, an embarrassing mistake to make!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now have it working, what a silly mistake!